# My monitor doesn't work with win10

Tags: display, external-display, display-settings

I have a monitor that does not work with my win10 laptop. I checked everything with my other laptop and the same cable (hdmi), monitor works no problem. I also tried my laptop with other monitor and same cable and everything works. So it is not the laptop or monitor it is the combination that is not working for some reason. I also tried downloading the drivers from samsung official site and it does not help.

I can see the monitor on my display settings but the signal is not getting through. I don't know what else to do. Any help is appreciated.

[display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhPdO.png)

Comment: Which mode is selected in _Display settings_? Duplicate, extend, something else? Can you post a screenshot with the problematic display selected?

Comment: 'same cable' doesn't tell us anything… what cable?

Comment: I added an image for display settings and to answer the cable is hdmi cable.